# Asp.net Mvc Controller return optional view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new Asp.net Mvc
I have one Controller and Two View.

Controller
-HomeController

View
-ProfileView
-PageView

I must return ProfileView or PageView

My codes are working but I can not be sure this is the right approach.

This my code

```
        if (Username == "Fatih")
        {
            return View("ProfileView");

        }
        else
        {
            return View("PageView");
        }
```

Comment: Sounds about right based on the information you provided.

Comment: I would reduce it to one `return` statement, but otherwise it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. The else block is not needed.just have the second return below the if block.